# How does another component listen from another component actions in react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Let say component **`A`** needs to know whether another component dispatched an action and the return response from let say asynchronous call to an API via redux-thunk, how does component **`A`** listen to that action and do something with the response?

Or how does any component listen to another components dispatch calls, regardless whether its a parent or a child? If that make sense.

---

I have just been learning *React/Redux* for couple of months just to give you an insight.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for dispatched actions from any component as long they are connected to your state tree, in other words your redux store. But make sure the components should be connected to the exact same piece of the state/store.

Comment: What if the dispatched action didnt really change any state? Let say a create form that does an async call to an api to create a post.It did not really change any state in the store but I want the view page component, to listen to that action and calls his own async to fetch that new post? If Im understanding it right. Please advise, could you also direct me to the code that listen to any action from inside the component?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can take actions without the state changing really but you can dispatch another action right before you're posting the form data which will change the state (say ```sendingFormData: false``` to  ```sendingFormData: true```) and then your view component would know about that state change and would act accordingly.

Comment: Thats actually what Im thinking too, but it seems ugly doing it that way. In essence I just want the responsible component to get the response from the API and do something according the result. But is this how redux work? You need to change the state to inside application to trigger an action? The changed actually happened in the database so thats actually what I want to listen to. But if this is the only way I can make it work. I supposed it will do. I'll give it a go.Thank you for the input.

Comment: Oh yea, I understand that bit! I just hoped that there is some sort of universal way to listen to action regardless. But that definitely what I can do!  Maybe a middleware I can look up to , that can do this but for now thats one way. Thank you ketan! Life saver.

Comment: Or in your component you can listen for the action payload. If the action payload is undefined or whatever initial value you've set for the reducer then your component won't bother but if there's data in the action payload which will be passed to the reducer then the component will know about it. Following is a little example:

```dispatch({type: "RECEIVED_FORM_DATA", data: //response from api})```

reducer: ```case: "RECEIVED_FORM_DATA": return {...state, data: action.data}```

component: ```this.props.reducerName.data !== null(or blank or undefined) ? //do something : null```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ketan below, It gave me an idea,to have a state in the store with

`action:{type:'ACTION_WHATEVER',payload:{} }`

And whenever an action is called, it change its underlying state to the action name and its payload.

The component can now call `componentWillReceiveProps` or `shouldComponentUpdate` and check the type and payload from the action object.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm missing something here, but you can use the "subscribe" method from Redux to listen to any changes in your Redux store, from any component. It takes in a listener callback function that will be invoked whenever the state of the store changes. These two sources explain it well:)
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-store-methods-getstate-dispatch-and-subscribe
https://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe

Comment: Actually, what happens if you dont actually change anything on the store? Because you are basically changing the database per se? Also how would you do a subscribe inside a component class?